# display only posts with a specific tag in page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display only posts with a specific tag (featured) to a page (page-featured.php) but nothing is showing up.

functions.php

```
function display_featured( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category() && $query->query_vars['category_name'] == 'featured') {
        $query->set( 'tag', 'featured' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'display_featured' );
```

page-featured.php

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php  ?>
<?php add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'display_featured' ); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

content here

<?php endwhile; else : ?>
no post found
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is there a better way to do this that actually works? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

modify your code in `function.php`

```
function display_featured( $query ) {

    if ( is_page('featured')) {  // Page ID, Page Title or Page Slug 
        $query->set( 'tag', 'featured' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'display_featured' );
```